# Leaflet GridLayer Vector Slicer with GeoDjango GeoJSON DOM

Tags: geojson, vector, web-mapping, geodjango, tiling

#### Overview

I am trying to use Leaflet's GridLayer Vector Slicer to split up a geojson with complex geometries being passed to my webmap via GeoDjango. I can't seem to get the tiled GeoJSON to display, however.

Documentation for VectorGrid is here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid

I can tile the same vector layer from a static framework when I assign the geojson text to a JS variable in a separate `geojson.js` file, then load that script and tile the vector using VectorGrid.

#### Static framework that works:

For example, from geojson.js:

```
var soil_ph = {"type": "FeatureCollection",... }
```

Then, from index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./geojson.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer( soil_ph, {
            rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                }).addTo(map);
...
</script>
```

This works fine and the display of the vector is snappy.

#### What I need, but doesn't work:

When I try to call a serialized GeoJSON view in GeoDjango, however, it doesn't seem to work.

From views.py:

```
def soil_ph_view(request):
    soil_ph_json = serialize('geojson', soil_ph.objects.all(), geometry_field="geom")
    return HttpResponse(soil_ph_json, content_type='json')
```

From urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^soil_ph/', views.soil_ph_view, name='soil_ph'),
    ...,
]
```

From index.html:

```
var soil_vector = $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'soil_ph' %}"
});

var soil_ph = L.vectorGrid.slicer(soil_vector2, {
    rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
});
```

I have also tried the following to pull the geojson data from the Django view:

```
var soil_vector = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'soil_ph' %}");
```

But no luck in getting it to tile and display.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: are you calling the vector grid slicer on the callback of the ajax call? `$.ajax(...).done(function(data){ L.vectorGrid.slicer(data, {...})});`

Answer (score 1):

On your view, change `content_type='json'` to `content_type='application/json'`

try:

`var soil_vector = {{ soil_ph_json }}`

I strongly recommend to change your configuration to use **render** and not *HttpResponse* https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render